# I don't understand the purpose and behavior of options "local to a window"

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, options

I don't understand the purpose of options that are "local to a window", such as for example `colorcolumn` and how they behave.

This is a sequence to demonstrate what I mean:

I start gvim. An empty, unnamed buffer appears.

I open an inexsting file without a file type associated with it:

```
:e c:\temp\abc.foo
```

write some text and set colorcolumn to 1

```
:set cc=1
```

and write the buffer to disk

```
:w
```

I split the window

```
:split
```

and edit another inexsting file

```
:e c:\temp\def.foo
```

When writing some text, I see that the color column is set to 1. Which is what I expected, since vim copies the value from the currently active buffer.

I set the color column to 2

```
:set cc=2
```

and write this buffer

```
:w
```

and start to edit yet another new file

```
:e c:\temp\ghi.foo
```

Again, the color column option value is copied from the currently active windows and set to `2`. This is still what I expected.

I switch the buffer to the buffer below `<Ctrl-W>+j` so that I am in `c:\temp\abc.foo`, the color column option value of which is `1`.

I start editing `def.foo` in that window:

```
:bu def.foo
```

Now, the color column option value is `2`, which I have previously set for that buffer, but not for that window. Here, I'd have expected the value to be `1` because it is an option "local to a window".

Can someone explain the rational of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

`local to window` doesn't mean every buffer you loaded in the same window has the same `local to window` options.

**create new window**

From [:h local-options](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#local-options) :

> When splitting a window, the local options are copied to the new window.  Thus
>   right after the split the contents of the two windows look the same.

**load new buffer**

When you load new buffer into window, `global window options` are used, the current `local to window` options are totally ignored, i believe this part works exactly the same as `local to buffer`. When you call `set cc=..`, both local and global values are changed, after you load new buffer, `colorcolumn` is set from the `global` one.

**load existing buffer**

From [:h local-options](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#local-options) :

> When editing a buffer that has been edited before, the options from the window
>   that was last closed are used again.  If this buffer has been edited in this
>   window, the values from back then are used.  Otherwise the values from the
>   last closed window where the buffer was edited last are used.

IMHO, the doc is not precise, it should be `the options from the window that the buffer was last unloaded (from window, not from memory) are used again`, it doesn't matter if the window is closed or not, so both `:q` and `:e another_buffer` counts.
It works like the buffer is never unloaded, everything is remembered, that's what most people desired. This explains why the last `colorcolumn` is 2.

If the `last unload window` doesn't exists, the buffer is currently loaded in other window or windows (might be multiple), i believe local options are copied from the last window that load the buffer.

**Experiment**

To help you understand the behavior of loading existing buffer, do this step by step :

```
vim /tmp/abc
```

Copy following commands and execute them with `:@+`

```
:setlocal colorcolumn=10
:wincmd v
:wincmd l
:setlocal colorcolumn=20
```

Left window has `colorcolumn` set to `10`, right window has `colorcolumn` set to `20`, check it with `setlocal colorcolumn?` (If you can see the column, check with your eye). Continue:

```
:h
:b abc
```

`:h` is used to avoid split with the same buffer. check `setlocal colorcolumn?`, it should be `20`, which is the same as bottom right window, as bottom right window is the last window that load the buffer when no `last unload window` exists. Continue:

```
1wincmd w
edit /tmp/balabala
setlocal colorcolumn=30
```

These commands goto left window, edit a new buffer (cause unload of original buffer), and set local `colorcolumn` to `30`, check it with `setlocal colorcolumn?`. Continue:

```
:b abc
```

Check `setlocal colorcolumn?`, it should be 10, the same as before it's unloaded, it's set from the `last unload window`. Continue

```
:2wincmd q
:h
:b abc
```

Check `setlocal colorcolumn?`, it should be 20, it's set from the `last unload window` (caused by `q`).